# Correcting Invalid Route Naming

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-cli

I'm currently working on a `CRUD` application - so far I've created an `index` route, a `show` route and `create` route and have moved on to creating an `update` method. I've gone ahead and added a route, template and a controller, but whenever I try to click on a link to my new template I receive an error letting me know the following:

`This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.`

I'm linking to the update path through the show page and can confirm that the `ID` I'm passing into the `link-to` function exists. This being the case, I think that there's something likely wrong with my route name but can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I assume it's likely something wrong with the nested routes.

I've tried altering the order of my routes and have put console log statements in the controller I anticipated hitting once the link-to statement was hit - so far I haven't entered the controller.

`app/router.js`

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('contact');
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('post');
    this.route('show', { path: '/:post_id' });
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:post_id/edit' });
    this.route('destroy', {path: ':post_id/destroy'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

`apps/routes/posts/edit.js`

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log('hit this when edit route is hit')
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

`app/templates/post/show.hbs`

```
<div class="jumbo show-posts">
 ...
</div>
{{log this.model.id}}
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <h3>{{#link-to "post.edit" post class=this.model.id}}Update post{{/link-to}}</h3>
  </div>
{{outlet}}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned a wrong route name. It should be `posts.edit` according to your `router.js`. You should pass at least one params to the `post.edit` route.

Have a look at my working [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/72d68e3103b90cae6540c92bdc83c29c)

Since you have mentioned `this.route('edit', { path: '/:post_id/edit' })`, the route will be expecting at least one of its parameters `:post_id` is present.

Modify you `{{link-to}}` as below,

```
{{#link-to "posts.edit" this.model.id}}Update post{{/link-to}}
```

You can access the post id in your controller through `params.post_id`,

```
model(params) {
  console.log('hit this when edit route is hit')
  return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);
}
```